# constant column value in select query output

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have one aggregate sum query as following.

```
select sum(size) as size from table;
```

which gives

```
size
100
```

I want to add const column value Product='Sugar' for which I changed query as per following

```
select 'Sugar' as Product, sum(size) as size from table;
```

Which works fine except one case when there is no row I am getting following output.

```
Product | Size
Sugar
```

Here I want empty row instead Sugar. Is there anyway to do this? expected result when no row is

```
Product | Size
```

I am using postgresql but putting other db as well.

Comment: just add `having sum(size) <> 0`...? or `where exists (select * from table)` or any number of other ways to do it. but probably you should show real schemas (a `table` cannot be called just `table`) and sample input data, as this example seems too simple to be of practical usefulness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `having` clause:

```
select 'Sugar' as Product, sum(size) as size
from table
having count(*) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having summing result to null in sizes, if that the case this query should work

```
select 'Sugar' as Product, sum(size) as size from table having sum(size) is not null ;
```

Comment: That will still give you a result row.

Comment: This will sum non-`null` sizes, and even if none exist, that still means a `null` result indicating that nothing was summed.

Comment: I realized it guys, i before believed it would ignore, i have edited my answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 'Sugar' AS product,
             sum(size) AS size
      FROM table) AS q
WHERE size IS NOT NULL;
```

Or use a `HAVING` clause, as suggested in the comment.

Comment: I don't want nested select statements.